# Kinect - How to get a consistent set of data?

Tags: ros, kinect, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently writing a program which is to use data from Kinect in order to perform image processing. I'm using the OpenNI-Kinect driver with Ubuntu 10.10 and ROS Diamondback.

The image processing needs color image, depth image and point cloud data, then I'm subscribing to the topics "camera/rgb/image_color", "camera/depth/image" and "camera/depth/points", which allows me to save pointers to the data, and - if needed - to save the different data as images or binary files.

My problem is that I don't know how to get a consistent set of these data, i.e. how to get RGB, depth and point cloud data which have the same time stamp.

The program is looping with a while(true) which contains:

- a cvWaitKey(1) to set the saving and to exit the loop,
- and a ros::spinOnce() to actually loop.

For the moment the program saves point cloud and depth data which have the same time stamp but the RGB never matches. Would you see how to get a RGB captured at the same moment ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9871/kinect---how-to-get-a-consistent-set-of-data-?/) by [Matthieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/488/matthieu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-05-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [approximate time syncronization policy](http://answers.ros.org/question/551/does-ros-provide-any-sync-mechanism-for-multiple), which mostly gets the right data bundle. Depth image and point cloud should have the exact same time stamp, the rgb image shouldn't be off more than 1/30 sec. I have recently introduced a filter that checks for time offsets in rgbdslam, and does get triggered every now and then.

Btw, better loop with `while(ros::ok()){ ... }` instead of `while(true)`. If your node gets killed, your program will stop.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general you can't expect to have perfect synchronization between RGB and depth for the Kinect. From the [openni_camera wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera):

> **Synchronization**
>
> Other than the Primesense devices, the
> Kinect does not support hardware
> synchronization. Thus the time points
> where the RGB image and the depth
> image are captured may be up to ~16ms
> away from each other. For all devices
> we use a Approximatetimesynchronizer
> to generate the point clouds
> /camera/rgb/points. For Primesense
> devices the hardware synchronization
> is turned on automatically if both
> streams are used (subscribing to image
>
> - depth).

Note that `/camera/depth/image` and `/camera/depth/points` both contain essentially the same information--the former is the depth of each point and the latter is the point cloud derived from that depth data. Subscribing to both of them simultaneously is probably overkill.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3